# Load a CSV as Simple Features R

Tags: r, sf

Is there a direct way to load a CSV as an sf? I've looked through the sf documentation and nothing jumps out at me, currently using:

```
my_csv <- read.csv('my_data.csv', header = TRUE)

my_sp <- sp::SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = data.frame(my_csv$y, 
my_csv$x), data = data.frame(my_csv$data), proj4string = CRS(BNG))

my_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(my_sp)
```

Comment: `sf` stands for "Simple Features", not "Special Features" (or even "Spatial Features").

Comment: lol, sorry. Any chance you know what OGR stands for? Not explained anywhere on GDAL.org it seems.

Comment: It stands for nothing any more  https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQGeneral#WhatdoesOGRstandfor

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you read a CSV with no options the driver doesn't know where the coordinate columns are so returns a data frame:

```
library(sf)
> st_read("./pts.csv")
Reading layer `pts' from data source `/home/rowlings/Downloads/SO/csv/pts.csv' using driver `CSV'
  id     x     y
1  1  10.1   2.1
2  2   2.4  12.1
3  3   3.2   4.5
Warning message:
no simple feature geometries present: returning a data.frame or tbl_df
```

So you need to pass a couple of options that end up telling the OGR driver where the coordinates are:

```
library(sf)
> st_read("./pts.csv", options=c("X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=x","Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=y"))
options:        X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=x Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=y 
Reading layer `pts' from data source `/home/rowlings/Downloads/SO/csv/pts.csv' using driver `CSV'
Simple feature collection with 3 features and 3 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 2.4 ymin: 2.1 xmax: 10.1 ymax: 12.1
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
```

and there's your `sf` spatial object.

OGR CSV driver documentation is here: https://gdal.org/drv_csv.html

Comment: Who downvoted and why? This is still a perfectly correct and, I think, optimal solution to the problem. I don't mind downvotes with constructive comments.

Comment: Great answer. I had no idea you could read in a CSV using st_read and convert it to sf in one go.

Answer (score 5):

If the column names aren't x and y you can first load csv then convert using `st_as_sf`.

```
df = read.csv('file.csv') %>% 
st_as_sf(coords=c("x_col_name","y_col_name"), crs=4326) # remember x=lon and y=lat
```

If your .csv doesn't have the coordinate columns as numeric data types, you'll have to convert prior to `st_as_sf`, or use `readr::read_csv()` to load in the file which will auto detect data types.

You can load in coordinates of any projection just remember to change the crs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to respond to the chosen answer, but it didn't work for me because it didn't recognize it as a simple feature even with the option chosen. I found the [answer at this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353557/read-csv-file-in-r-using-sf) where you use st_as_sf

```
t=read.csv('tab.csv')
```

```
t=st_as_sf(t, coords=c(x,y), crs=4326)
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/231657)