# Read CSV file in R using sf()

Tags: r, csv, sf

I can see that it's possible to load in csv data to R (as per here: [Load a CSV as Simple Features R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305403/load-a-csv-as-simple-features-r)), however, it appears to me that there is a limitation on the range of delimiters allowed given the direct use of GDAL (COMMA/SEMICOLON/TAB/SPACE, see "Layer Creation options" [here](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/csv.html)).

So with [sp()](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/) I could use `sep` as follows:

```
pow_pointX <- read.csv("./data/poi_2015_12_scot06340459.csv", sep="|")
```

Given that the pipe character `"|"` is default for Ordnance Survey datasets distributed in the UK, this seems like a serious limitation. Has anyone found a workaround that doesn't require the use of `sp()`?

Comment: Not clear what you are getting at here. The `read.csv` is a base function and has nothing to do with sp or sf. The function results in a data.frame that can then be coerced into a spatial object. It is looking like your issue is reading the file. Do you, in fact, have multiple delimiters or are you trying to use a pipe delimiter? If you need more flexibility in reading your flat file take a look at `read.table`

Comment: Sorry - I should add in a more substantial vignette to show the issue I'm referencing- will do so asap and edit question

Comment: Perhaps what you want is not something to read a table, but something to convert the read-in CSV to simple features?

Answer (score 2):

The GDAL CSV driver documentation documents that only the following separators are implemented:

```
SEPARATOR=COMMA/SEMICOLON/TAB/SPACE
```

Alternatively, read in as a plain CSV using `read.csv` or `read.table` or `data.table::fread` perhaps, and then convert to `sf` using:

```
sfd = read.table(filename, sep="|")
sfd = st_as_sf(sfd, coords=c("long","lat"), crs=27700)
```

(adjusting parameters to fit your CSV file).